# A strange edit conflict - Exact edit, exact time, but new edit made within 5 minutes overwrites another user's edit

Tags: bug, edits

In one answer's [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13445007/revisions), Mario and
I tried to convert the all caps answer to lower case. It turned out that our edits were exactly the same and were made in the exact same second, but with my edit coming first and Mario's coming second. I remember that
Mario's edit history was blank. Then about 3 minutes later, I edited the answer to remove
"Simple and quick fix for you hopefully."

However, the edit history incorrectly shows that that that sentence was *added* to the answer, not removed 
from it. (The two edit histories for me and Mario were also changed.) I assume it's because the edit was made
 within 5 minutes so **the edit will overwrite the current one, even if it belongs to a different user**.

Can you help fix the edit history so it correctly reflects the current version of the answer?

Maybe the system should overwrite edits made within 5 minutes only if the same user as that of the post's last edit made that edit. Otherwise the system should make a new entry in the edit history.

Comment: I have seen this as well in a handful of cases, I wish I'd held onto the revision links.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed with a rollback to your edit.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I will accept your answer as soon as I am allowed to.  However, I still find it strange that the edit history was handled wrong when I made the edit within 5 minutes.  Maybe the system should overwrite edits made within 5 minutes only if the same user as that of the post's last edit made that edit.  Otherwise the system should make a new entry in the edit history.

Comment: @PeterO. Yeah, that'd make sense. This seems like an edge case, but it may be worth fixing in the long run. I'm going to untag the question so that it's not longer status-completed.